# Error 404 page not found in Angular 16 + Node.js + MongoDB web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb, express

I recently started working with Express framework from node.js and MongoDB. With angular as front-end code (written by a friend), I wanted to create a simple web app. I wanted to integrate my signup page with my server and check if things work. I would start the server with `node server.js` (server.js is the main file in my server). Then I would start Angular with `ng serve --port 8080`. When ever I load the signup page, and click the submit button. It returns page not found error. I think other than my query to create and my routing addresses everything else should be fine. This is what the code looks like. Am I missing something? do I have to do anything in particular to integrate my front-end to my back-end?.
This code is based on the code present on the BezKoder website. This is the code for server,

Server.js

```
import express,{json,urlencoded} from 'express';
import cors from "cors";
import db from './App/Models/index.js';
import {patientrouter} from './App/Routes/patient.routes.js'

const app = express()
var corurl = {origin: "http://localhost:8080"}

app.use(cors(corurl))
app.use(json())
app.use(urlencoded({extended: true }))

/* REQUESTS and ROUTES */

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({Message:"Hello, Welcome to Wearable."})
})

app.use('/patient', patientrouter);

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}.`);
});
```

patient.controller.js

```
import db from '../Models/index.js'

const PatientEntry = db.patients

function Patientcreate(req,res){
    if (!req.body.Name || !req.body.Mobile_Number || !req.body.Gender || !req.body.Username || !req.body.Password || !req.body.ID) {
        return res.status(400).send({ Message: "Content is empty, please rectify." })
    }

    const patient = new PatientEntry({
        Name: req.body.Name,
        Mobile_Number: req.body.Mobile_Number,
        Gender: req.body.Gender,
        Username: req.body.Username,
        Password: req.body.Password,
        ID: req.body.ID,
    })

    patient
    .save()
    .then(Data =>{
        res.send(Data)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
          message:
            err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Patient."
        });
    })
}
export {Patientcreate}
```

patient.model.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const Patientschema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ID: Number,
    Name: String,
    Mobile_Number: Number,
    Gender: String,
    Username: String,
    Password: String
})

export default PatientSignup => {
    Patientschema.method("toJSON", function() {
        const { __v, _id, ...object } = this.toObject();
        object.id = _id;
        return object;
      });
    const patient = PatientSignup.model("Patient", Patientschema)
    return patient
}
```

patient.routes.js

```
import {Patientcreate, PatientFindAll, PatientFindOne, PatientUpdate} from '../Controllers/patient.controller.js'
import {Router as routerman} from 'express'

const patientrouter = routerman()
patientrouter.post("/",Patientcreate)
//patientrouter.get("/",PatientFindAll)
patientrouter.get("/Find/:Name",PatientFindOne)
patientrouter.put("/Update/:ID",PatientUpdate)

export {patientrouter}
```

The Angular front-end code,

signup.component.html

```
<div>
  <div class="submit-form">
    <div *ngIf="!submitted">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Name">Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="title"
          required
          [(ngModel)]="patient.Name"
          name="Name"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Username">Username</label>
        <input
          class="form-control"
          id="description"
          required
          [(ngModel)]="patient.Username"
          name="Username"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Password">Password</label>
        <input
          class="form-control"
          id="description"
          required
          [(ngModel)]="patient.Password"
          name="Password"
        />
      </div>

      <button (click)="savepatient()" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="submitted">
      <h4>Tutorial was submitted successfully!</h4>
      <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="newpatient()">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Initially the code was a bit different and I kept getting errors for NgModel(which I assumed was happened beacause I was trying to use NgModel in html forms, and I tried importing it but didn't solve the error), so I replaced it with this.

Signup.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Patient } from '../models/patient.model';
import { PatientService } from '../service/patient.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
  patient: Patient = {
    Name: '',
    Username: '',
    Password: '',
  }
  submitted = false

  constructor(private patientservice: PatientService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  savepatient(): void {
    const data = {
    Name: this.patient.Name,
    Username: this.patient.Username,
    Password: this.patient.Password
  }

  this.patientservice.create(data)
      .subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          console.log(res);
          this.submitted = true;
        },
        error: (e) => console.error(e)
      });
  }

  newpatient(): void {
    this.submitted = false;
    this.patient = {
      Name: '',
      Username: '',
      Password: ''
    };
  }

}
```

patient.service.ts (the service I created)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Patient } from '../models/patient.model';

const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/patient';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PatientService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  create(data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(baseUrl, data);
  }
}
```

patient.model.ts

```
export class Patient {
    ID?: any;
  Name?: string;
  Mobile_Number?: string;
  Gender?: String;
  Username?: String
  Password?: String
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';
import { PatientloginComponent } from './patientlogin/patientlogin.component';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    PatientloginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';
import { PagenotfoundComponent } from './pagenotfound/pagenotfound.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'login',component: LoginComponent,children:[
    {path:'patientlogin',component:PatientloginComponent},
    {path:'caretakerlogin',component:CaretakerloginComponent},
    {path:'doctorlogin',component:DoctorloginComponent}
  ]},
  {path: 'signup',component: SignupComponent},
  {path: '**', component: PagenotfoundComponent},

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I tried changing the baseurl and the paths that I had passed in the server side, but it didn't seem to do anything. I also tried to check if it was a form code issue or query issue, but I couldn't figure it out. I know this is a lot of code and a very long question, but I wasn't sure which parts of the code are relevant here. Help me find my mistake. thank you